# Access apache server from windows machine hosted on mac over LAN

Tags: php, macos, apache

Hosting my app for development on MAC OS by running the below command in app folder:

```
sudo php-S localhost:80
```

I am able to access it on the same MAC machine but not others connected over lan.
Below is apache's piece of config. This file lies in

> macintoshHD>etc>apache2

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:
Listen *:80
<IfDefine SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 8080
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen *:80
</IfDefine>

#
```

Any suggestions truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean `php -S` and not `php-S`, this has absolutely nothing to do with Apache. You're using PHP's [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

I suggest you [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php#example-413) closer next time...

> **Example #6 Accessing the CLI Web Server From Remote Machines**
>
> You can make the web server accessible on port 8000 to any interface with:
>
> ```
> $ php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
> ```

The key there is to use `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` so you would use

```
$ sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```